# Remove everything all lines except those ending with the string ".com"

Tags: bash, text-processing

I am working on a script, and I have the current input as :

```
devdb.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com
dev-redis.cnwoho.ng.0001.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com
2.5
dev-redis.cnwoho.ng.0001.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com
```

How can I remove the `2.5`? The number can be anything, since it's a timeout, developers might adjust it. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: 2.5 would not be a whole number. What do you mean by remove? Delete the entire line? Will it be lines with a number only?

Comment: Would it be fair to reformulate the issue as "extract all lines ending with the string `.com`"? Or, "extract all lines that contains letters"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the title asks for one thing, while the body of the question asks for a distinct thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use grep to remove the unwanted line:

```
grep -v '^[0-9][0-9]*\(\.[0-9][0-9]*\)\?$'
```

A bit shorter equivalent using extended regular expressions:

```
grep -vE '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$'
```

If the `0` in `0.5` is optional, you can use for example

```
grep -vE '^([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|^\.[0-9]+)$'
```

Comment: Just to be picky, as OP says it's a timeout, a possible format is `.5`, in that case you command could fail. But that's just speculation.

Comment: I agree, i dunno why is the timeout in that format. This worked out. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Can u tell me how I can remove file-path in similar manner. Such as /var/log/msmtp/msmtp.log. I have domain names which also contain / so I cannot use a / replacement regex.

Comment: @WeareBorg You should ask a new question, but try something first and share it.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your title, "*Remove everything other than all lines ending with the string `.com`*" this is a straightfoward use of `grep`

Reverse the condition, so that it's "*Keep all lines ending with the string `.com`*"

```
grep '\.com$' file
```

The `grep` command matches with Regular Expressions, and since `.` is a special character for REs (it matches any single character) you have to escape it. The `$` symbol binds to *end-of-line*.

Comment: The original title was [Remove whole numbers from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/632041/revisions).

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity The OP changed the title, possibly in response to a comment of mine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed '/^[0-9]*\.*[0-9]*$/d' file
devdb.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com
dev-redis.cnwoho.ng.0001.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com
dev-redis.cnwoho.ng.0001.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `awk`:

```
awk '/\.com$/' file
```

This will only print lines that end in `.com`.